# Show that $X_n$ is bounded in probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that a sequence of r.v. $Y_n$ is bounded in probability. That is, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $M_\epsilon > 0$ such that $\mathbb{P}\big( \left| Y_n \right| > M_\epsilon\big) < \epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Furthermore, suppose we have a sequence of set $B_n$ such that $\lim_n \mathbb{P}\left(B_n\right) = 1$. For any $n$, for any $\omega \in B_n$, we have $\left| X_n(\omega) \right| \le \left|Y_n(\omega)\right|$. How do I show that $X_n$ is bounded in probability as well?

I stared at the definitions but did not see what I could do. I think somehow I need to use the fact that $\lim_n \mathbb{P}\left( B_n\right) =1$ but don't know how.

---

**Update**: Here is my real question. Here is what I am reading

[image]

What I don't understand is the sentence "This is bounded in probability by law of large numbers". I see that the thing on the RHS converges to a fixed number (its expectation, namely). As a result, RHS is bounded in probability (forgot the proof, but I think it's correct?). But for the LHS, first, this whole inequality does not even hold on the whole sample space $\Omega$. Indeed, it only holds on $A_n = \{ \hat{\theta}_n \in B\}$. So I don't really see why the LHS is $O_p(1)$?

Also the book defines "bounded in probability" in the following way.

[image]

Comment: Pick $M$ so that $P(|Y_n|>M)<\epsilon/2$ and pick $N$ so that $P(B_n)>1-\epsilon/2$ if $n>N$.  Then $|X_n|>M$ in only one of 2 ways, each way having prob.  $\le\epsilon/2$ , and so on.

Comment: I don't think you can show it in as much generality as you are given for $Y_n$ (i.e. that for any $\epsilon$ you can select $M_\epsilon$ so that $P(|X_n|>M_\epsilon)<\epsilon$ for all $n$). Here's why: what if the first finitely many $B_n$ are just $\emptyset$? Then you have absolutely no information about those $X_n$'s. I think you want to define bounded in probability to only refer to the tail, i.e. "for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_\epsilon,M_\epsilon$ such that if $n \geq N_\epsilon$ then $P(|Y_n|>M_\epsilon)<\epsilon$".

Comment: @Ian The definition I have in the book is $\sup_\alpha P\left( \left|X_\alpha\right| > M\right) <\epsilon$, so...

Comment: I think it should be $\limsup$. Are you sure it is $\sup$?

Comment: @amsmath Yes. Please see my update

Comment: @3x89g2 Ok, then you get the claim by using kimchi lover's part and the fact that every random vector is tight.

Comment: @Ian Does my update help?

Comment: I see, yes you've implicitly assumed that a random vector is at least a.s. finite from which it follows that it's automatically tight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $M'$ such that $P(|Y_n|>M') < \epsilon/2$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Then choose $N$ such that $P(B_n) > 1 - \epsilon/2$ (i.e., $P(B_n^c) < \epsilon/2$) for each $n\ge N$. Then for $n\ge N$,
\begin{align*}
P(|X_n|>M')
&= P(\{|X_n|>M'\}\cap B_n) + P(\{|X_n|>M'\}\cap B_n^c)\\
&\le P(\{|X_n|>M'\}\cap B_n) + \frac\epsilon 2\\
&\le P(\{|Y_n|>M'\}\cap B_n) + \frac\epsilon 2\\
&\le P(|Y_n|>M') + \frac\epsilon 2 < \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Since $X_n$ is tight for each $n\in\{1,\ldots,N-1\}$, you find $M_1,\ldots,M_{N-1}$ such that $P(|X_n|>M_n) < \epsilon$. Hence, with
$$
M := \max\{M',M_1,\ldots,M_{N-1}\}
$$
you get that $P(|X_n| > M) < \epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

---

Here is a proof for the fact that any random variable $X : \Omega\to\mathbb R$ is tight. Let $\Omega_N := \{|X| > N\} = \bigcap_{n\le N}\Omega_n$. Then $\bigcap_N\Omega_N = \emptyset$ and hence (by continuity of measure)
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X| > n) = \lim_{N\to\infty}P(\Omega_N) = 0.
$$
Hence, for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $P(|X|>n) < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. In particular, $P(|X|>N)<\epsilon$.

Comment: What about a thanks or an upvote to appreciate my effort and time that I spent on your problem?

Comment: Thank you. I will upvote your answer.