# Rigorous justification of dividing both sides by $o_p(1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, asymptotics

Suppose

$$-\Psi_n\left(\theta_0\right) = \left(V + o_p\left(1\right)\right) \left(\tilde{\theta}_n - \theta_0\right) $$

where $\tilde{\theta}_0 \overset{p}\to \theta_0$, $V$ is a non-zero constant, and that

$$\Psi_n\left(\theta_0,X_1,\cdots,X_n\right) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \psi\left(X_i,\theta_0\right) \overset{p}\to 0$$

Why is it true that

$$\sqrt{n} \left(\tilde{\theta}_n - \theta_0\right) = - V^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n \psi\left(X_i,\theta_0\right) + o_p\left(1\right)\,?$$

My book says "since $V + o_p(1)$ is eventually invertible, so we apply $(V + o_p(1))^{-1}$ on both sides". What does that exactly mean? Also how do we deal with the $\sqrt{n}$?

This question is related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560959/show-that-x-n-is-bounded-in-probability).

**Some updates:**

I think we can rewrite what we have as

$$-\sqrt{n} \Psi_n\left(\theta_0\right) = \sqrt{n} V \left(\tilde{\theta}_n - \theta_0\right) + \sqrt{n} \left(\tilde{\theta}_n - \theta_0\right)o_p(1)$$

Move things to the other side, we get

$$\sqrt{n} \left(\tilde{\theta}_n - \theta_0\right) = \frac{-\sqrt{n} \Psi_n\left(\theta_0\right) - \sqrt{n} \left(\tilde{\theta}_n - \theta_0\right) o_p(1)}{V}$$

So I think the problem boils down to show that, in fact,

$$-\frac{\sqrt{n} \left(\tilde{\theta}_n - \theta_0\right) o_p(1)}{V} = o_p(1)$$

But I don't know how to show this.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that there is an unstated central limit theorem-type assumption about  $\Psi_n$, such as $E|\psi(X_i,\theta_0)|^2 < \infty$ and something like an iid or ergodic assumption on the $X_i$ sequence.

Comment: @kimchilover Would you mind elaborating? What would happen if second moments are finite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not supplied all the assumptions your book is using, so it's hard to tell if the  claimed result follows from them.  But one can guess that your book is like 99% of the other math stats books, and makes the assumption that the $X_i$ are iid and that $E\psi(X_i,\theta_0)=0$ and $E\psi(X_i,\theta_0)^2<\infty$ and hence the central limit theorem holds for  $\Psi_n(\theta_0)$ in the form $$ \sqrt n \Psi_n(\theta_0) = \frac 1 {\sqrt n} \sum_{i=1}^n \psi(X_i,\theta_0)-E  \psi(X_i,\theta_0)) \Rightarrow N(0,V^2),$$
where $V^2$ is the variance of $\psi(X_i,\theta_0),$ and where $\Rightarrow$ denotes convergence in distribution.

Under such assumptions, $Z_n=\sqrt n \Psi_n(\theta_0)$ (as I'll call it, to make my typing easier) is $O_p(1)$ quantity.  Now your equation becomes
$$\sqrt n (\tilde\theta_n-\theta_0) = -(V+o_p(1))^{-1}Z_n.$$
Presumably the matrix $V$ is invertible, and then using the fact that $(V+o_p(1))^{-1} = V^{-1}+o_p(1)$, you have 
$$ \sqrt n (\tilde\theta_n-\theta_0) = -V^{-1}Z_n + Z_no_p(1).$$
The last term here, $Z_no_p(1)$, converges to $0$ in probability  by [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).

That's the standard story plot line that seems closest to what you are asking about.

As for the matrix inversion.  If $V$ is invertible, so is $V+tB$, for very small $t$, as the power series $(V+tB)^{-1} = V^{-1} - t V^{-1}BV^{-1} + t^2 V^{-1}BV^{-1}BV^{-1}\cdots,$ with $t$ playing the role of $o_p(1)$.
Or more simply: suppose $V$ is invertible.  The map $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ mapping invertible matrices to their inverses is continuous at $V$, so the ["continuous mapping theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Convergence_in_probability) implies that $(V+o_p(1))^{-1} = V^{-1}+o_p(1)$.

Comment: My confusion is actually then line after "Now your equation becomes"... What happened there? Why can we divide both sides? What if for some $\omega$ in the sample space, the thing we divide is zero?

Comment: Multiply both sides of your very first equation by $V+o_p(1))^{-1}$ and by $\sqrt n$.  There are not many $\omega$ that cause trouble, because of the $o_p(1)$ and the continuity of matrix inversion.

Comment: Ummm I need to think about it. By "not many", do you mean that the number of $\omega$ that causes trouble has measure zero?

Comment: Has measure that approaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$, is what $o_p(1)$ means.

Comment: So I think what I need to show is this. Suppose $X_n = Y_n Z_n$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$. If for each $n$, $Z_n = X_n/ Y_n$ on $B_n \subset \Omega$, where $\lim P(B_n) = 1$, then if $X_n/Y_n \overset{d}\to W$, then $Z_n \overset{d}\to W$ as well. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  Or, I think so, because I've lost track of what $X_n$ and $Y_n$ mean in terms of your original problem.  But the bit about "Suppose ..." looks true and useful.  Maybe you should revise your original question with your current understanding, putting in all relevant details.  It's pretty hard to check proofs in these little comment post-it note boxes.

Comment: Right, I will definitely write down a cleaner version. Basically I was looking at $ - \sqrt{n} \Psi_n\left(\theta_0\right) = \left(V + o_p\left(1\right)\right) 
 \sqrt{n} \left(\tilde{\theta}_n - \theta_0\right) $. We know that $-\sqrt{n} \Psi_n\left(\theta_0\right)$ converges in distribution, and $V + o_p(1)$ converges in probability. Although for any $n$, $\tilde{\theta}_0 - \theta_0 = \frac{-\sqrt{n}\Psi_n}{V + o_p(1)}$ does not hold for all $\omega$, the sets $B_n$ on which this equation holds satisfied $P(B_n) \to 1$, that's why we can "divide" both sides?

Comment: Yes.  I agree: that's why.

Comment: I see. Thank you! I'm so happy :D